# React JS forcing js files from server only on new build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have this React JS application to which critical patches are being pushed every now and then and I cannot ask my users to do a hard refresh every time. The current method I'm using to bust the cache and reload from the server is I build the app and then manually go to the index.html and append "?v=number". Also I see several chunks of js being generated, I'm assuming all of them are cached too.

Is there a more elegant solution to automate this process and get the js files from server ONLY when there is a new build?

I'm using `react-scripts` to build my project.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from this article:

https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk

> TL;DR - SemVer your app and generate a meta.json file on each build
> that won't be cached by the browser. Invalidate cache and hard reload
> the app when there's a version mismatch.

And you can use this npm package to manage your `meta.json`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-clear-cache